# Parent element of an element absolutely positioned absolute must accomodate the height of the child

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

.Background {
background-image:url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517524285303-d6fc683dddf8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1275&q=80");
height: 220px;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.Relative {
position:relative;
}
.Absolute {
 position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

h2 {
 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Main">
<div class="Relative">

<div class="Background"></div>

<div class="Absolute">
<h1>Hi</h1>
<h1>Hi</h1>
<h1>Hi</h1>
<h1>Hi</h1>
</div>
</div>

<footer>With absolute positioning, an element can be placed anywhere on a page. The heading below is placed 100px from the left of the page and 150px from the top of the page.</footer>
</div>
```

The absolutely positioned element is displayed over the footer. What I'd like is for the element that has the class **Relative** to take up the height of it's child that has the class **Absolute** so that it doesn't display over footer.

Comment: What do you want.. I don't understand :D

Comment: `class Relative` is  taking height from `Background` child , which has `    height: 220px;`   so `class="Absolute"`  display over footer.

Comment: you want to display Absolute in between image & footer?

Comment: Parent element don't take the height of any absolute child, if you want to set the height of parent you can do it via js only

Comment: If you want background should always comes behind text then make background absolute and text to relative.

Comment: Is there any other mechanism where I can make the footer not overlap with absolutely positioned element only with css. @PiyushVerma

Comment: Let me share a solution hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now here I make the "background" absolute to the relative div and make your "absolute" div to relative so that it will give the parent element height of your content div.
Background will always take the height and width of parent element in this case it will never overlap the footer no matter how much text you can put. Hope it helps

```css
.Background {
background-image:url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517524285303-d6fc683dddf8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1275&q=80");
height: 220px;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index:0;
}
.Relative {
position:relative;
}
.Absolute {
position:relative;
z-index: 1;
}

h2 {
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Main">
<div class="Relative">

<div class="Background"></div>

<div class="Absolute">
<h1>Hi</h1>
<h1>Hi</h1>
<h1>Hi</h1>
<h1>Hi</h1>
<h1>Hi</h1>
</div>
</div>

<footer>With absolute positioning, an element can be placed anywhere on a page. The heading below is placed 100px from the left of the page and 150px from the top of the page.</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function setHeight() {
    let rel = document.querySelector(".Relative");
    let abs = document.querySelector(".Absolute");

    let hei = abs.scrollHeight;
    hei += abs.offsetTop;

    rel.style.height = hei + "px";

}

setHeight();

window.addEventListener("resize", setHeight);
```

```css
.Background {
    background-image:url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517524285303-d6fc683dddf8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1275&q=80");
    height: 220px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.Relative {
    position:relative;
    background-color: #333;
}
.Absolute {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 150px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Main">
         <div class="Relative">
            <div class="Background"></div>
            <div class="Absolute">
               <h1>Hi</h1>
               <h1>Hi</h1>
               <h1>Hi</h1>
               <h1>Hi</h1>
            </div>
         </div>
 <footer>With absolute positioning, an element can be placed anywhere on a page. The heading below is placed 100px from the left of the page and 150px from the top of the page.</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this without using javascript? Only using pure css?